# Worker variabled was destroy after app close

Tags: android, variables, background-process, worker

After an exhausting day of trying to implement a process that runs in the background (even after closing the application) and checks for new notifications, I have reached a successful end.
**I thought I was coming to a successful end.**

I have the following implementation

**Boot receiver:** - checks that the device is turned on and that the user is logged in

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) && !getEmail(context).isEmpty()) {
            startService(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**utils:** - starts / stops recurring activities (or restarts if the user changes how often the activity is to be performed)

```
public class utils {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationsChecker";

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static NotificationsHelper notificationsHelper;
    public static MutableLiveData<Boolean> newNotification = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public static void startService(Context context) {
        createNotificationsHelper(context);

        if (newNotification == null || newNotification.getValue() == null) {
            SQLiteData sqLiteData = new SQLiteData(context);
            newNotification.setValue(sqLiteData.isUnreadNotification());
        }

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationsWorker.class, getNotificationsFrequency(context), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag(TAG)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
    }

    private static void createNotificationsHelper(Context context) {
        notificationsHelper = new NotificationsHelper(context, APIUtils.getAPIService(), newNotifications -> {
            if (newNotification != null && newNotification.getValue() != null && !newNotification.getValue()) {
                newNotification.setValue(newNotifications);

                if (newNotification.getValue() && !newNotification.hasActiveObservers())
                    showNotification(context, 1, "default_system_notification", "New notification", "There is new notification in Wedos app");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void stopService(Context context) {
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG);
        Log.d("Notification service", "notification value is: " + newNotification.getValue());
    }

    public static void restartService(Context context) {
        stopService(context);
        startService(context);
    }

    public static void destroyService(Context context) {
        stopService(context);
        if (notificationsHelper != null)
            notificationsHelper.destroy();
    }
}
```

**Worker** - checks for new notifications

```
public class NotificationsWorker extends Worker {

    public NotificationsWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        Log.d("Notifications worker", "Worker initiated");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        //if (notificationsHelper != null)
            notificationsHelper.prepareAPI();

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

**NotificationsHelper** - returns the result from `notificationsHelper.prepareAPI()` back to `utils`

```
...
//API call
...
listener.onCheck(newNotifications); //depends on API result
```

the problem is that Worker returns me the following when I close the application:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.package.example.ui.notifications.NotificationsHelper.prepareAPI()' on a null object reference`

**The overall idea is as follows:**

after restarting the device, it is checked whether the user is logged in. If so, startService() methos is called, which checks for new notifications.

If the user logs out of the application, the serviceDestroy() method is called, which cancels the PeriodicWorker and destroys the NotificationsHelper (connection to the SQLite database, etc.).

After a successful login to the application, the startService() method is called, which creates new NotificationHelper and starts the PeriodicWorker again.

If the user changes the frequency of polling new notifications, the restartService() method is called, which restarts the PeriodicWorker.

If the application is not running (I check with hasActiveObservers()), I will display a notification.

If the application is running, I will do nothing, because

```
newNotification.observe((LifecycleOwner) context, aBoolean -> {
            if (aBoolean) newNotificationPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else newNotificationPin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
```

which visually indicates whether there are unread notifications, is called from each activity or fragment.

Of course, the newNotification variable must still maintain its set state to correctly indicate new notifications (ie when unread notifications are detected in the background and I open the application, I have to see a visual about the unread notification)

Thanks for help

Comment: I beleive the nullpointer exception comes from the prepareApi() method , something is null there , check using the debugger , and check if the response is successful

Comment: @takieddine Unfortunately, the error points directly to the `notificationsHelper.prepareAPI();` line, so I'm afraid the notificationsHelper is null.

Comment: prepareApi() is a function where you have fecthed your api call right , so check if the data you re getting from api is not null and make sure the prepareApi doesnt return something null

Comment: @takieddine OK, I will check it tomorrow, but I'm using this function in another class (I think) and there it is OK. Btw in prepareAPI() I'm fetching API and storing notifications to SQLite DB

Comment: When your app crashes , your logcat will show lines on which you should click and it will take you to the exact line of the crash issue

Answer (score 0):

**"the problem is that Worker returns me the following when I close the application"**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.package.example.ui.notifications.NotificationsHelper.prepareAPI()' on a null object reference
```

If you close the application before the Worker finishes, and then start the Application again, a new instance of that Worker will be created with the same Worker.id before. When it happens the **doWork** will be called again. So, if that guy (NotificationsHelper) is not been created yet, when the Worker is started again, we get that NPE.

Comment: However, NotificationsHelper should be created only once, when calling the startService() method in the utils class. This means that the NotificationsHelper variable should remain the same when you close the application, right?

Comment: check my answer (I added logcat)

Comment: If the Application is really closed, means that NotificationHelper instance does not exists anymore, because the process was finished.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat:

```
2020-12-22 12:03:47.867 28181-28208/com.example.android D/Notifications worker: Worker initiated
2020-12-22 12:03:47.876 28181-28212/com.example.android D/Notifications worker: doWork initiated
2020-12-22 12:03:47.881 28181-28212/com.example.android D/Notifications worker: notificationsHelper is null
2020-12-22 12:03:47.882 28181-28211/com.example.android E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=26e5ac17-51f0-4f38-9c61-ba29e76525cc, tags={ com.example.android.BackgroundService.NotificationsWorker, NotificationsChecker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.ui.notifications.NotificationsHelper.prepareAPI()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:298)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.ui.notifications.NotificationsHelper.prepareAPI()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.BackgroundService.NotificationsWorker.doWork(NotificationsWorker.java:25)
        at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2020-12-22 12:03:47.884 28181-28211/com.example.android I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=26e5ac17-51f0-4f38-9c61-ba29e76525cc, tags={ com.example.android.BackgroundService.NotificationsWorker, NotificationsChecker } ]
```

EDIT:

After the device restarts, Worker will run and display a notification if there is a new notification. On the second run, notificationsHelper is already null. Without any interaction with the application.